# Beer Crosswords?

Tags: discussion

Should we consider having beer crosswords permitted as on topic? Would it be of interest to put them on, say a "challenge week/day" in order to build up our user list and more interest to this site in general. The [Latin Crossword](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22903/latin-crossword) question had been proposed for the new [Latin Language](https://latin.stackexchange.com/) site! Of course we would have to make sure we do not infringe on any copyright status in doing so.

I would like to know your thoughts on this topic, both pro and con!

At the moment of writing this question, we have not had a question in 9 days. This may just be a temporary (band aid) solution!

What do you guys think?

Comment: FYI, I tried to answer your question a few times, but I honestly don't know. So I've asked on [meta.se](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277261/using-off-topic-questions-to-build-beta-site-activity). I didn't link your question specifically in case you didn't want the direct attention (and nay-sayers potentially downvoting you here), but if you don't mind that then I'll link you from my post.

Comment: @AndrewCheong Linkage is fine with me.